# How to multi-select vertices and have them snap to the set guide

Tags: vertices, transforms

I have multiple vertices that are not quite aligned with the guide (128 width) I created. When I select individual vertices and translate them (G), they will snap to the guide when I complete the move. If I have multiple ones selected, they snap to the average of all the selected vertices.

Is there a setting somewhere that will snap each of them individually to the guide if I have multiple selected and move them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To snap multiple vertices at the same time you would have to use the Shrinkwrap modifier set to "Nearest Vertex".